# My listbox does not display Treeview widget

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to build a table inside a listbox using Treeview. When I do so, it does not display anything and I am not sure why. I have pasted a copy of my code below (`alist` is the listbox).

```
def show_loans():
    alist.delete(0,END)
    Results = student.Loaned_Books()
    treeview = ttk.Treeview(alist)
    treeview["columns"] = ["Member ID", "Full Name"]
    treeview["show"] = "headings"
    treeview.heading("Member ID", text="Member ID")
    treeview.heading("Full Name", text="Full Name")
```

Comment: You never called `.pack()` (or any other geometry management method) on your Treeview.

Comment: Why are you putting a treeview inside a listbox? That is a very strange thing to do. What problem do you think that solves?

Comment: I used listbox because I have a few of buttons below and I expect the display i.e. the listbox to change when the buttons are clicked - so I thought if I use listbox then I can clear it using `alist.delete(0,END)` where alist is the listbox and for scrolling purposes as well